# Orion NGSIv2 subscription that notifies cygnus in NGSIv1 - Case of data geoJson

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I'm performing an Orion NGSIv2 subscription that notifies cygnus in NGSIv1 using "attrsFormat":"legacy" otherwise cygnus crashes.
Here the notification by example:

```
{
    "description": "Subscription if parking is full",
    "subject": {
        "entities": [{
            "idPattern": ".*",
            "type": "parking"
        }],
        "condition": {
            "attrs": ["full"]
        }
    },
    "notification": {
        "http": {
            "url": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:5050/notify"
        },
        "attrsFormat": "legacy",
        "attrs": ["full"]
    }
}
```

My question is to be sure that there is no loss of information using the "attrsFormat":"legacy" to notify cygnus in NGSIv1 in case the attribute under condition of changing contains geographical information like geoJson.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes, Cygnus currently only accepts NGSIv1 notifications. Nevertheless, that not means you cannot create NGSIv2 subscriptions: as you mention, the `attrsformat` field must be used, with `legacy` value, in order the notifications are sent in NGSIv1 format. More details [here](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/installation_and_administration_guide/ngsiv2_support/index.html).

Regarding the content of a NGSIv1 notification derived from a NGSIv2 subscription, all the attributes and their types are maintained. It does not matter `geo:json` is a special type for NGSIv2 and means nothing for NGSIv1: the type is sent in any case.